# fadeIn/fadeOut effect keeps looping when hovered over an anchor tag - jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, hover, fadein

I am building an image gallery. The image container has a paragraph that is relatively positioned at the bottom of the image and this paragraph contains a link. By default the paragraph display is set to none.

I want the paragraph to fade in when an image is hovered but without firing multiple fade-ins when the hover event occurs on image, paragraph and link. So far, I managed to prevent double-firing when mouse enters the hidden paragraph, but jQuery goes into crazy looping when the mouse enters the anchor tag and I cannot prevent it in any way.

Here is my code:

```
imgHover: function() {
   var bigImage = this.imageContainer.find('img');
   var imgInscription = $(bigImage).siblings('p');
   $(bigImage)
   .mouseenter(function(event) {
         event.stopPropagation();
         $( imgInscription ).stop().fadeIn(500)})
  .mouseleave(function() {    
         $( imgInscription ).stop().fadeOut(500);});}}
```

And this is relevant HTML:

```
<div id="pic-container">
   <img src="images/gallery/taureau_peace_large.jpg"  alt="Peaceful Lake View" />
   <p><a href='#' title='Read about adventure details'>Read about adventure >>> </a></p>
</div>
```

And some CSS just in case:

```
 #pic-container p {
 position:relative;
 top:-55px;
 display:none;}
```

Any help will be much appreciated:)

EDIT: The only solution I came up with so far was to bind fading to an image and paragraph separately. Not the best solution, but works so I stick to it until I find out something better.

```
var imgInscription = $('#pic-container p');

$('#pic-container img').hover(function(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $(imgInscription).stop().fadeIn(500);
}, 
function() {
    $(imgInscription).stop().fadeOut(500);
});

$(imgInscription).hover(function(event) {
     event.stopImmediatePropagation();
     $(this).stop().fadeIn();
}, 
function() {
    $(this).stop().fadeOut(500);
});
```

Comment: Where are you calling imgHover()? And you are only claling it once right?

Comment: I have a constructor function and my gallery object already exists so the function runs automatically on hover. Effect works, but misbehaves

Comment: Adding a fiddle would be nice

Answer (score 0):

```
.mouseenter(function(event) {
     event.stopPropagation();
     $( imgInscription ).stop(true).fadeIn(500)})
  .mouseleave(function() {    
         $( imgInscription ).stop(true).fadeOut(500);});}}
```

try this, ive added the "true" in the .stop

Comment: naah, that doesn't work. I tried to try every possible combination with stops:). I think the problem is that p and img are siblings and p sits on the image at the same time. The only solution I can think of now is to bind fading to two elements separately with propagation prevents.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a var in your constructor that stores the state of the paragraph. Example:

```
this.pIsActive = false;
```

Then in your mouseenter and mouseleave events, you can have a check that only proceeds with the fadeIn and fadeOut when `this.pIsActive` is false or true (respectively). Your callback (when fade is complete) for fadeIn and fadeOut would change `this.pIsActive`. For example

```
imgHover: function() {
    var bigImage = this.imageContainer.find('img');
    var imgInscription = $(bigImage).siblings('p');
    $(bigImage)
    .mouseenter(function(event) {
         if (!this.pIsActive) {
             $( imgInscription ).stop().fadeIn(500, function() {
                 this.pIsActive = true;
             });
         }
     })
    .mouseleave(function() {    
    $( imgInscription ).stop().fadeOut(500);
        if (this.pIsActive) {
             $( imgInscription ).stop().fadeOut(500, function() {
                 this.pIsActive = false;
             });
         }
    });}}
```

Comment: I tried this one but again it prevents propagation to p element only. Crazy looping on anchor still occurs. I watched changes of this.pIsActive values on console.log() and it's changed when hover occurs on image; so when hover occurs on hidden paragraph and image, the state is already changed and anchor hovering continues to misbehave.